# Eclipse add abstract method in abstract class

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, after I added one abstract method in my abstract class, is there a way to ask Eclipse add an empty implementation in all subclasses of that abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the "type Foo must implement inherited abstract bar()" in the problems view, select Quick Fix from the context menu and apply the fix to all affected classes. However, they will only get the empty method stub so I'm not aware of a way to add the same implementation body to all subtypes.